# Riemann integrability and Darboux's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I have some elementary problems with understanding the concept of "integrability".

The lecture notes I'm reading at one points state that some function like $f_{\operatorname{step}}(x) = \lfloor 4x \rfloor$ is "Riemann integrable" on $[0, 1]$ because it is a step function. At another point they state "Darboux's theorem": if $f [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, then $f'$ will assume every value between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$.

Isn't this a contradiction? If $f_{\operatorname{step}}$ is integrable, it must be some function's derivative and as such should take on every value between $f_{\operatorname{step}}(0)$ and $f_{\operatorname{step}}(1)$ which it clearly doesn't (i.e. any non-integer value). Is Riemann integrability not the same as the "ordinary" integrability I know from Calculus? (There are similar questions on this site but after reading them I still don't quite get it).

Comment: "If $f$ is integrable, it must be some function's derivative" is not true.

Comment: What is the "ordinary" integrability that you know?

Comment: @davidlowryduda: But isn't it true at least for $f_{\operatorname{step}}$ here?

Comment: The correct statement is one part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus as follows: If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ and is continuous at $x_0\in(a,b)$, then $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and is differentiable at $x_0$. Now your $f_{\text{step}}$ fails to be continuous at points of the form $k/4$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and even further, we can check independently that the function $$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f_{\text{step}}(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$ fails to be differentiable at those points. So the Darboux' Theorem applies for $F$ only when $k/4 \notin (a, b)$.